# Comparison of topologies, problem with notation

Tags: general-topology

Consider topologies $\tau _R, \tau _K$ on $\mathbb{R}:$
$$\tau_R := \left\lbrace U\subset\mathbb{R} : U=\emptyset\quad\mbox{or}\quad U = \bigcup_{j\in I} (a_j,b_j), a_j<b_j,\forall j\in I\right\rbrace$$
$$\tau_K := \left\lbrace U\subset\mathbb{R} : U=\emptyset\quad\mbox{or}\quad \mathbb{R}\setminus U\ \mbox{is finite}\right\rbrace $$
Decide whether $\tau _K\subset\tau _R$ or vice versa.

Let's try $\subset$.
Let $U\in\tau _K$ and assume $U\neq\emptyset$ and $U\neq\mathbb{R}$. The only way we can achieve $\mathbb{R}\setminus U$ being finite is when we take $U = \mathbb{R}\setminus\{x_1, x_2,\ldots ,x_n\}$. Assume without loss of generality $x_1<x_2<\ldots <x_n$.

**Trouble:** I want to write $U = (-\infty, x_1)\cup (x_1, x_2)\cup\ldots\cup (x_n, \infty)$ [hence $U\in\tau_R$], but there is no such thing as $\infty$ as a real number, now is there? [I know it must sound like nitpicking, since we use this all the time, but in this context the meaning doesn't appear obvious]. What is an acceptable way to treat this problem?

$\supset$ doesn't hold for sure, though. Pick any $(a,b)=U\in\tau_R$, then $\mathbb{R}\setminus U$ is infinite and $U\notin\tau _K$

Comment: $-\infty$ is not a real number, but $(-\infty,x_1) = \{r \in \mathbb{R} \mid r < x_1\}$ is still a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that if $U \in \tau _K$, then $\Bbb R \setminus U$ is finite, so it is closed in $\tau _R$ (which is the "usual" topology on $\Bbb R$), so $\Bbb R \setminus ( \Bbb R \setminus U ) = U$ is open in $\tau _R$, i.e. $U \in \tau _R$, therefore $\tau _K \subset \tau _R$.

On the other hand, $(0,1) \in \tau _R$, but since its complementary is infinite, clearly $(0,1) \notin \tau _K$. This shows that the inclusion $\tau _K \subset \tau _R$ is strict.

---

In case you ask why finite sets are closed in $\tau _R$, it will be enough to show that a singleton $\{x\}$ is closed, since then every finite set will be a finite union of singletons (= closed sets), and *finite* unions of closed sets are closed.

Notice that

$$\{x\} = \Bbb R \setminus \big( (-\infty, x) \cup (x, \infty) \big) = \Bbb R \setminus \left( \bigcup _{n < x, n \in \Bbb Z} (n, x) \cup \bigcup _{n > x, n \in \Bbb Z} (x, n) \right)$$

and since arbitrary unions of open intervals are open, their complementary must be closed, so indeed singletons are closed.

Comment: Alternatively, consider a finite set $A$. Any convergent sequence $(x_n), x_n\in A$, must converge in $A$, therefore $A$ is closed.